# Directory.EnumerateFiles read order

Tags: c#, arrays, file, indexing, ienumerable

What is the default read order for the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` method? Is it consistent?

In my experience so far it seems to be by the date the files were created but I haven't been able to find confirmation of this.

Reason I ask is because part of a program I am working on loads binary files from directories into objects which are in turn loaded into arrays. These objects reference each other by arrays of indices, meaning the order they are loaded into their arrays needs to remain consistent (to avoid shifting indices).

While I'm here, I have another minor question. When files are deleted, it obviously changes the indices of the files loaded into arrays no matter what I do. Any suggestions for avoiding this problem? I've avoided using a dictionary up until now due to worries about storage (would rather not be storing arrays of textual keys if I can avoid it) but if it's the only feasible approach, I may have to implement it anyway.

---

**EDIT:** After the excellent tips from your answers, I've refactored to a dictionary approach using the names of the files. The performance impact has been fairly negligible and the readability and maintainability are both vastly improved so it's worked out quite well.

Comment: Why not just keep a reference instead of an index?  You wouldn't have to worry about indexes being shuffled if you did this.

Comment: Because of the way file serialization works. If I were to save files containing references via serialization and then load those files, I'd be loading the entire object tree every time resulting in mass duplication. For example, if Car references Tire and Truck references Tire and they are both saved and then loaded, I would have 2 duplicate instances of Tire.

Comment: Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), about `GetFiles` (which essentially calls `EnumerateFiles`): *The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort() method if a specific sort order is required.* I suggest you, as the documentation says, to use your own sorting method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's not documented - therefore even if you *can* spot a pattern, you shouldn't rely on it. It may depend on the version of .NET, or the version of the operating system, or simply change between service packs. Instead, if you need some specific order, you should sort it yourself. Of course that unfortunately requires finding all the file names before processing them, but it will give you consistency.

To be honest though, it sounds like you've got a very fragile data model. You haven't really told us enough about what you're doing to fix it, but using the integer index of a file within the results of `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is *surely* not the best approach.

If you used the file *name* instead of the index, that would allow you to process files as you read them, potentially - but there may well be even better approaches, depending on what you're trying to do. Using the name should still be reasonably cheap - it'll just be a single string reference instead of an integer, and even if it's used in multiple places, it'll be several references to the same string object.

Answer (score 23):

The underlying Win32 API used by .NET is `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`. The [documentation specifically states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The order in which this function returns the file names is dependent on the file system type. With the NTFS file system and CDFS file systems, the names are usually returned in alphabetical order. With FAT file systems, the names are usually returned in the order the files were written to the disk, which may or may not be in alphabetical order. However, as stated previously, these behaviors are not guaranteed.

So no, you cannot guarantee the order the files are returned. The other answers provide sufficient ways to work around this behavior.

Comment: I like this technical detail and the link.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation does not specify the order, but you can always force the order you want by employing LINQ's `OrderBy` function.

You can skip index changes by clearing out references to `null`, rather than actually removing  the items from the array. The tradeoff here is that you must now check if the item at the given index is `null`.

If you have a more readable data structure in mind that is based on a `Dictionary`, consider switching to it, and ignore the efficiency concerns until your profiler tells you that you must optimize this particular part of your code.